# Check if there is a table in the database - always returns 0

Tags: sql

I need to check whether a given table, more specifically two are in the database, for this I have written such SQL command

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = "__pricelist_countries"
  AND table_schema = "__pricelist_ranges"
```

Unfortunately - although a table with this name is present in my database, SQL always returns 0 rows, which in turn causes the same condition to occur in PHP. Hence the question - how do I make a mistake, or how can I otherwise construct a command to be correct and return the result, or is this table actually or not?

Comment: You are looking for schema's, not tables. Use `where table_name = ...`.

Comment: Here is a problem, thanks dude :D

Comment: Don't forget to switch the `and` to `or` as well (or use `IN()`)

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, use single quotes for string literals. E.g. `'__pricelist_countries'`.

Comment: `table_schema = "__pricelist_countries"
  AND table_schema = "__pricelist_ranges"` is always false. A single row can't have two values at the same time.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Using double quotes for string literals is invalid standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You should use OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '__pricelist_countries' 
   OR table_schema = '__pricelist_ranges'
```